# Limit registration to 4 people on form sign up

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have some code, seen below. I would like some help changing this into normal PHP statement and not object orientated. Not very good with PHP still learning.

```
<?php        
    $connection=mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) from database_users";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $users = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if ($users['COUNT(*)'] < 4) {
?>

    // html goes here, outside of the php tags

<?php
    } else {

        echo "Sorry, you have reached the user account limit.";

    };
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Charlie

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Using mysqli in this way is preferred.

Comment: Dude this is vanilla php there is OOP here. i dont think you can do more simple that this ;)

Comment: Hi @JonathonReinhart It has come up with an error, and I'm not used to using object orientated. It works on my local host but comes up with Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/.../public_html/.../users.php on line 119

Comment: @user3004356 He's probably referring to the OOP mysqli calls, like `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) is only available on PHP >= 5.3.0.

Comment: PHP version 5.3.27 @JonathonReinhart

Comment: It will help in the future to point out the specific problem you're having, as opposed to asking for general advice on how to do something. Here, searching for that error message leads to tons of advice.

Comment: How you are trying to access `$users` will give an undefined index error as well, as it won't have the index of `count(*)`.  Instead, in the query, you'd want to use `SELECT count(*) as something FROM...` and access it with `$users['something']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this you can use an alias for `COUNT(*)`

```
<?php        
    $connection=mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database");
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt from database_users";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $users = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
    if ($users['cnt'] < 4) {
?>

    // html goes here, outside of the php tags

<?php
    } else {

        echo "Sorry, you have reached the user account limit.";

    }
?>
```

Comment: While it's true that he should use an alias for `count(*)`, that isn't the reason it's failing for him.  You should say why you neglected to use `::get_result()` in your response to make it more helpful ^^